# Confusing math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve this question? I came across it and is really confused.

The payment of Jon was bigger by $960$ than the payment of David.
After the payment of David got increased by $10\%$, Jon and David got the same payment amount.

$\text{A}$. We will mark with $X$ the payment of David in the beginning and using the $X$ find the payment of Jon.

$\text{B}$. Find out the payment of David in the beginning.

How can I solve this? Any hints?

Comment: Your question might get more views if you give it a more informative title.  The current one describes most questions on this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $J$ = payment of John and $X$ = payment of David. Then we know that $J = X + 960$. Furthermore, $1.1X = J$. Now substituting the first equation into the second we obtain: $1.1X=X+960 \iff 0.1X=960 \iff X=9600 \rightarrow$ $J=9600 + 960 = 10560$ (we obtain J from substituting $9600$ into the first equation).

Comment: Okay I get it, but I don't get the part on how did you get to 1.1?

Comment: The $1.1$ comes from the fact that David's payment is increased by $10\%$. This means that he now gets $1.1$ * "what he originally earned". Hence, he now gets $1.1X$

Comment: Oh.. correct me if I am wrong; Davids payment was 1.0. After the increase it became 1.1, therefore it is 1.1X?

Comment: 10% is 10/100 = 0.1 without percent units. i.e.  10% of X is equal to 0.1*X.  Similarly 10% increase means 110% which is 1.1.

Comment: @user73230 You are indeed correct. $1.0X$ is his original salary. Then after the increase he earns $1.1X$. So his salary got multiplied by 1.1 (because it increased by $10\%$).

Answer (score 2):

We know that: (Jon's Payment) = (David's Payment) + $960$

But, we also know that: (Jon's Payment) = (David's Payment) + $0.1$ (David's Payment)

Let Jon's Payment be deonted by $J$ and David's Payment by $X$. Thus, we have:

$J=X+960$ and

$J = X + 0.1 X$

Does that help?

Comment: Can you explain a bit on how do I solve this? and what is the 0.1? How did u get it?

Comment: "After the payment of David got increased by 10%, Jon and David got the same payment amount". A 10% increase would be $\frac{10}{100}=0.1$. See [cruise's](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/397519/76635) answer for the mechanics of how to solve the pair of equations.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are expected to use "algebra," but it might be useful to note that we can figure out the answer without algebra. A $10\%$ increase in David's salary let him catch up to Jon. The *increase* in David's salary was $960$. This is $10\%$ of his old salary, so his old salary must have been $9600$.